# Why is PowerPivot Experiencing XML Parsing Error on refresh/interaction

Tags: excel, xml, powerpivot

I started experiencing an XML Parsing error with my excel workbooks that have a power pivot data model. The error looks like this: [image]

I was able to track down the Temp files that are created by PowerPivot and open the XML file in question and it seems like the closing the </Load statement at the very end of the XML is not being generated correctly:

XML File at Line1, Column 3105 : [image]

The very last part is suppose to be </load to closeout the loading process. if I manually change all the XML files that are effected by this manually the power pivot model connects properly like it's suppose to. But since these are Temp files they get cleared out after every session and if I reopen the workbook and try to run the model it happens again.

There are no external data sources for this model. All data sources are native to the workbook structured in tables in different sheets.

Every single XML file that is generated by this particular PowerPivot Model is having an issue with the ending <load statement.

This just started happening about 3 week ago with a model that has been running successfully for over a year. No modifications have been done to the model for over a year.

Does anyone know what is causing the creating of these temp XML files to be corrupted in this way?

Comment: I have been experiencing the same exact issue - has been driving me crazy and it is making this power query and pivot functionality unusable.  Which particular file was creating the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Mystery solved.

The newest release of Dell Data Protection | Encryption Enterprise Edition was causing this parsing error. Once it was disabled for testing it started working just fine like before.